# How to install and support node.js app from git on Ubuntu server

Tags: git, node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Full stack of commands for install **node.js** and **app** from **git** on the **Ubuntu** server (Ubuntu 12.04 on Amazon EC2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## #INSTALL

### #install oracle java

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

### #insatll git

sudo apt-get install git

### #install node, npm & forever

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
sudo npm install forever -g

### #download server repository

:~$ mkdir webserver
:~$ cd webserver$
:~/webserver$ git init
:~/webserver$ git remote add origin https://webserverteam@bitbucket.org/webserverteam/server.git
:~/webserver$ git config --global user.name "webserverteam"
:~/webserver$ git config --global user.email "webserverteam@gmail.com"
:~/webserver$ git config --global push.default "matching"
:~/webserver$ git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always
:~/webserver$ git config --global color.status auto
:~/webserver$ git config --global color.branch auto
:~/webserver$ git config branch.master.remote origin
:~/webserver$ git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
:~/webserver$ git pull

### #install dependencies

:~/webserver$ npm intsall

### #edit settings you need (if you need)

:~/webserver$ nano app.js

### #setup iptables

#trivial user have no access to 80 port, so we run server on 8080 and do redirect 80->8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

### #run web server app:

:~/webserver$ forever start app.js

## #SUPPORT

### #after every restart

#unfortunatly I could not "save\run after start" iptables with trivial rights
:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
:~$ cd webserver$
:~/webserver$ forever start app.js

## #trivial update from git

:~$ cd webserver$
#check running forever processes
:~/webserver$ forever list 
#kill forever process number 0
:~/webserver$ forever stop 0
:~/webserver$ git pull
:~/webserver$ forever start app.js

## #full update from git

:~$ cd webserver$
:~/webserver$ forever list
:~/webserver$ forever stop 0
 
:~/webserver$ git fetch --all
:~/webserver$ git reset --hard origin/master
:~/webserver$ git pull
#edit settings you need (if you need)
:~/webserver$ nano app.js 
:~/webserver$ forever start app.js

Comment: There is no need for Java here and it is a too specific answer, why clone that repo? And [that repo](https://bitbucket.org/webserverteam/) does not exist anymore.

Comment: Java - for some packages, like yicompressor. I just spend a few hover to figure how to install good version of java, so I decide to add this here as well. Neweble people, like me, often even hard to undertsand from errors that some packages need it. I think, it will help.

Comment: that repo - just an example, you must take you own repo